# two buttons in the same form

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

I have two buttons in the same form, and each one should take me to a different servlet (.java).
Any ideas?!
onClick = response.sendRedirect is not working!!!!

thi is the code :

```
            "<button type =\"button\""+
            "class=\"textenormal\" onClick=\"response.sendRedirect('http://localhost:8080/SiteFinal/AjoutNouveauHoraire');\""+
            "style=\"background-color: #99AABB; color: 'black'; height: '35px'; margin-top: '5px'; margin-bottom: '5px'; width: '400px';\""+
            "onmouseover=\"this.style.cursor='hand';this.style.fontWeight='bold';this.style.borderWidth='1px';this.style.borderStyle='groove';\""+
            "onmouseout=\"this.style.fontWeight='normal';this.style.borderStyle='none';\">"+
            "Vous desirez Enregistre l'horaire dans un autre Cursus <br/>"+
            "ou/et avec un autre Enseignant?"+
            "</button>"+    
            "</td>"+
            "</tr>"+
            //"</Form>"+
                "<tr bgcolor=\"#F1F1E4\">"+
                "<td colspan=\"2\" align=\"center\""+
                    "valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\""+
                    "class=\"textenormal\">"+
                    "<input type =\"button\" value=\"Enregistrer\" "+
                    "class=\"textenormal\" "+
                    "onClick=\"response.sendRedirect('http://localhost:8080/SiteFinal/EnregistrerHoraire');\" "+
                    "style=\"background-color: #99AABB; color: 'black'; height: '20px'; margin-top: '5px'; margin-bottom: '5px'; width: '180px';\""+
                    "onmouseover=\"this.style.cursor='hand';this.style.fontWeight='bold';this.style.borderWidth='1px';this.style.borderStyle='groove';\""+
                    "onmouseout=\"this.style.fontWeight='normal';this.style.borderStyle='none';\">"+
                    "<input type =\"reset\" value=\"Reset\""+
                    "class=\"textenormal\""+
                    "style=\"background-color: #99AABB; color: 'black'; height: '20px'; margin-top: '5px'; margin-bottom: '5px'; width: '180px';\""+
                    "onmouseover=\"this.style.cursor='hand';this.style.fontWeight='bold';this.style.borderWidth='1px';this.style.borderStyle='groove';\""+
                    "onmouseout=\"this.style.fontWeight='normal';this.style.borderStyle='none';\">"+
                "</td>"+
```

Comment: You misunderstand client side and server side.

Comment: So i just can use one submit button!?

Comment: How is that your conclusion from my comment? `HttpServletResponse` is a server side component while HTML and javascript are client side components.

Comment: Because first i had just one submit button and it worked!!!

Comment: but now that i have two buttons i dont know what to do ! :S
Thank you for your answers

Comment: Are you using a javascript framework or library which happens to have a `response` object with a `sendRedirect()` method? This looks like server-side java, as Sotirios mentionned. So unless you're using some special javascript framework, there's no way it can work.